# How to find the DataListItem item type without using FindControl?

Tags: asp.net, iteration, datalistitem

I want to be able to determine if my DataListItem type is of type RadioButton in C# code behind.

Is this possible?

Alternatively if it is not type DropDownList that would also work.

Isn't there a way to some kind of check such as

`if(item.ItemType.Equals(HtmlInputRadioButton)){
//
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***item.ItemType*** is an enum. Type will never be ***HtmlInputRadioButton***

```
  public enum ListItemType
  {
    Header,
    Footer,
    Item,
    AlternatingItem,
    SelectedItem,
    EditItem,
    Separator,
    Pager,
  }
```

Instead, the code should be like this -

```
void Item_XXXX(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // Make sure MyRadioButtonId is an ID of HtmlInputRadioButton
        var htmlInputRadioButton = e.Item.FindControl("MyRadioButtonId") 
          as HtmlInputRadioButton;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option is:

```
var radio = item as RadioButton;
if(null != radio)
{
    // It's a radio button!
    // The "as" keyword will return null if the cast fails
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the clearer

```
if(item is RadioButton)
{
    var radio = (RadioButton)item;
}
```

But that results in two casts, which is less efficient.

Comment: I think my problem is once again I am in a web control. It is not resolving.

Comment: ok I really wanted to avoid using findcontrol.. I may just switch to jQuery to validate the quiz.. if that is a must.

Comment: @JoJo What are your qualms with using FindControl?